# Gzip in asp.net for Response and Request?

Tags: asp.net, gzip

When I use Gzip, I put some code in `global.asax` which zip the **reponse** from the  server to my client.

But my page contains a lot of text ( no view state - pure text).

When I save it - it uploads it all as a plain text.

Is there any way to zip the uploaded content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable [GZip](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression) on the server.

By doing it in your application, do you ever have a moment where you *don't* want it?  Why wouldn't you want it on all the time?

Comment: as i mentioned i did put the gzip code. what i think is that its only for the response data from the server to the client. my problem is that i have a page with a lot f text and when i press submit to save it - it uploads it all as plain text and not zipped data . this isaving takes some time and i would like to reduce the time  by gzip the data from the client to the server. thats my question